# Why I am getting huge amount of duplicate records?

Tags: sql, oracle

From below query I am getting 118 records. What I want that I want to get user name from Emp_master table. I want to compare D.prepared_by with two columns(Emp_Initial and Emp_no) of Emp_Master table and want to get Emp_Name from Employee table.

```
SELECT D.Prepared_By, D.location, C.INSTRUMENT_NO, D.EQP_SRL_NO, D.INSTRUMENT_NAME, B.PLAN, A.DETAIL, C.MAINTENANCE_FREQ, C.PERIOD, 
    C.MAINTAIN_ON_DUEDATE,C.MAINTENANCE_DUE_DATE
  FROM ACTIVITY_DETAIL A,ACTIVITY_MASTER B,MAINTENANCE_SCHEDULE C,   INSTRUMENT_MASTER D
  WHERE A.PLAN_ID = B.PLAN_ID and D.instrument_no=C.instrument_no and   C.plan_id=B.plan_id and  C.activity_id=A.activity_id 
    AND (C.INSTRUMENT_NO,C.PLAN_ID,C.ACTIVITY_ID,C.MAINTENANCE_DUE_DATE)  =(SELECT E.INSTRUMENT_NO,E.PLAN_ID,E.ACTIVITY_ID,
    max(E.MAINTENANCE_DUE_DATE) FROM MAINTENANCE_SCHEDULE E
    where C.PLAN_ID = E.PLAN_ID and C.instrument_no=E.instrument_no and     C.activity_id=E.activity_id group by E.INSTRUMENT_NO,E.PLAN_ID,E.ACTIVITY_ID
      ) and  trunc(c.maintenance_due_date) between To_Date('1-NOV-2019','DD-MON-RRRR') and To_Date('5-NOV-2019','DD-MON-RRRR')
      and d.P_MANITENANCE_REQ<>'N';
```

I modified it like below but I am getting 1.7 million rows. Actual data is only 118 rows.

```
SELECT E.Emp_Name, D.Prepared_By, D.location, C.INSTRUMENT_NO, D.EQP_SRL_NO, D.INSTRUMENT_NAME, B.PLAN, A.DETAIL, C.MAINTENANCE_FREQ, C.PERIOD, 
        C.MAINTAIN_ON_DUEDATE,C.MAINTENANCE_DUE_DATE
      FROM ACTIVITY_DETAIL A,ACTIVITY_MASTER B,MAINTENANCE_SCHEDULE C,   INSTRUMENT_MASTER D, Emp_Master E
      WHERE (E.Emp_Initial = D.Prepared_By) or (TO_CHAR(E.Emp_No) = D.Prepared_By) and A.PLAN_ID = B.PLAN_ID and D.instrument_no=C.instrument_no and   C.plan_id=B.plan_id and  C.activity_id=A.activity_id 
        AND (C.INSTRUMENT_NO,C.PLAN_ID,C.ACTIVITY_ID,C.MAINTENANCE_DUE_DATE)  =(SELECT E.INSTRUMENT_NO,E.PLAN_ID,E.ACTIVITY_ID,
        max(E.MAINTENANCE_DUE_DATE) FROM MAINTENANCE_SCHEDULE E
        where C.PLAN_ID = E.PLAN_ID and C.instrument_no=E.instrument_no and     C.activity_id=E.activity_id group by E.INSTRUMENT_NO,E.PLAN_ID,E.ACTIVITY_ID
          ) and  trunc(c.maintenance_due_date) between To_Date(P_FROM_DATE,'DD-MON-RRRR') and To_Date(P_TO_DATE,'DD-MON-RRRR')
          and d.P_MANITENANCE_REQ<>'N';
```

Comment: Readability is a feature. These two queries are all scrunched up, with multiple elements on a line, which makes them hard to read and especially hard to compare. Perhaps some kind stranger will fix the layout but it would have been better if you had taken the time to lay them out properly. Because you see it's not just us that find these queries hard to read, it's **you**. Somewhere in your second query you have omitted a join restriction and so you get a product. If your query was easier to read you would have found it easier to spot the omission.

Comment: It is also traditional for SQL mavens on this site, when confronted with Old Skool implicit joins, to offer a Tip Of The Day and urge you to use explicit ANSI SQL:92 join syntaxes. But in this case they would have a point. If you had joined all the tables using INNER JOIN syntax you would have been forced to specify the ON clause and so you would have been much less likely to omit the join criteria whose absence is generating all those duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get thousands of "duplicates" because your second query has a loose or missing join criterion, which makes the result set a product of rows. (If you look closely at the result set you'll probably see those aren't full duplicates: rather, they are permutations of all selected values.)

You have added a new table `Emp_Master E` and want to join it to `INSTRUMENT_MASTER D` by either one of two criteria. You wrote the join like this:

```
WHERE (E.Emp_Initial = D.Prepared_By) 
or (TO_CHAR(E.Emp_No) = D.Prepared_By)
```

My guess is that rogue OR is the culprit. If you apply the parentheses to wrap that condition the product will collapse.

```
WHERE (E.Emp_Initial = D.Prepared_By 
       or TO_CHAR(E.Emp_No) = D.Prepared_By)
```

Comment: After modify query with your answer Now I am getting 62 records

Comment: So that tells you you have values of `D.Prepared_By` which don't match any values of `E.Emp_Initial` or `E.Emp_No`. So maybe you need an outer join? Or maybe you need to revise your join criteria? I don't know. It's your data model and your business rules.